# I cant get the subtotal. Shopping cart with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, calculation

Good evening maam/sir. I need some help on how can i select all my total price per product so i can make my subtotal. i've already done some research on how to get subtotal but still no luck. i've already try looping it using for loop or .each but still wont work i've been trying to fix for almost 15 hrs already

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
 <th>Product</th>
  <th>Restaurant</th>
  <th>Quantity</th>
  <th class="text-center">Price</th>
 <th class="text-center">Total</th>
 <th> </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<?php foreach ($cart as $value): ?>


<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
  <div class="media">
  <a class="thumbnail pull-left" href="#"> <img class="media-object" 
  src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic- 
  2/72/product-icon.png" style="width: 72px; height: 72px;"> </a>
 <div class="media-body">
   <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="#"><?php echo $value['product_name'] 
  ?></a> 
  </h4>
    <h5 class="media-heading"> by <a href="#"><?php echo 
  $value['restaurant_name'] 
  ?></a></h5>
 <span>Status: </span><span class="text-warning"><strong><?php echo 
  $value['status'] ?></strong></span>
  </div>
  </div></td>
  <td class="col-md-1 text-left"><strong class="label label- 
  danger">None</strong></td>
 <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1" style="text-align: center">
 <input type="email" class="form-control qty" id="qty" name="qty" 
 value="">
  </td>
  <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong class="prodprice" 
  id="prodprice"><?php echo $value['price'] ?></strong></td>
  <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center" ><strong id="prodtotal" 
   class="prodtotal"></strong></td>
    <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
  <span class="fa fa-remove"></span> Remove
  </button></td>
 </tr>
 <?php endforeach ?>    
  <tr>
   <td>   </td>
   <td>   </td>
   <td>   </td>
   <td><h5>Subtotal</h5></td>
   <td class="text-right"><h5><strong>$999.99</strong></h5></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td><h5>Estimated shipping</h5></td>
    <td class="text-right"><h5><strong>$9.999.99</strong></h5></td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
   <td>   </td>
   <td><h3>Total</h3></td>
  <td class="text-right" id="total"><h3><strong>$9.999.99</strong></h3> 
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></span> Continue Shopping
    </button></td>
     <td>

    <a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/checkout') ?>"><button type="button" 
    class="btn btn-success" >
     Checkout <span class="fa fa-play"></span></a>
     </button></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
     </table>
     </div>

<script>
        $('.qty').on('input', function() {
          var selector = $(this).closest("tr") //get closest tr
          var price = parseInt(selector.find('.prodprice').text()) //get price
          var qty = parseInt($(this).val());
          var prodtotal = price * qty;
          var subtotal;
         console.log(price)
          console.log(qty)

          var a =$("#totalcart").val();
          selector.find('.prodtotal').html(prodtotal); //add total in same row.

            for(var i =0; i <= a; i++) {
             subtotal=price[i] * qty[i];
              console.log(subtotal)
            }

         
         

           
        })




            
        </script>
```

[image: Shopping Cart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.each` loop to iterate through your `prodtotal` element and on each iteration check if the value  inside `prodtotal` is not `""` depending on this use `parseInt($(this).text())` or consider value as  `0` and then add this total inside your `subtotal`

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('.qty').on('input', function() {
  var selector = $(this).closest("tr") //get closest tr
  var price = parseInt(selector.find('.prodprice').text()) //get price
  var qty = parseInt($(this).val());
  var prodtotal = price * qty;
  selector.find('.prodtotal').html(prodtotal); //add total in same row
  var result = 0;
  //loop through total column
  $("tr .prodtotal").each(function() {
    //check if the text is not ""
    result += ($(this).text().trim() != "") ? parseInt($(this).text()) : 0
  })
  //add result inside subtotal
  $(".subtotal").text(result)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Restaurant</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th class="text-center">Price</th>
        <th class="text-center">Total</th>
        <th> </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
          <div class="media">
            <a class="thumbnail pull-left" href="#"> <img class="media-object" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic- 
  2/72/product-icon.png" style="width: 72px; height: 72px;"> </a>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">
                <a href="#">
              Abc
                </a>
              </h4>
              <h5 class="media-heading"> by
                <a href="#">
                Astar
                </a>
              </h5>
              <span>Status: </span><span class="text-warning"><strong>Good</strong></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="col-md-1 text-left"><strong class="label label- 
  danger">None</strong></td>
        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1" style="text-align: center">
          <input type="email" class="form-control qty" name="qty" value="">
        </td>
        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong class="prodprice">55</strong></td>
        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong class="prodtotal"></strong></td>
        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
  <span class="fa fa-remove"></span> Remove
  </button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
          <div class="media">
            <a class="thumbnail pull-left" href="#"> <img class="media-object" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic- 
  2/72/product-icon.png" style="width: 72px; height: 72px;"> </a>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">
                <a href="#">
                Abc1
                </a>
              </h4>
              <h5 class="media-heading"> by
                <a href="#">
                A star 3
                </a>
              </h5>
              <span>Status: </span><span class="text-warning"><strong>ok</strong></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="col-md-1 text-left"><strong class="label label- 
  danger">None</strong></td>
        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1" style="text-align: center">
          <input type="email" class="form-control qty" name="qty" value="">
        </td>
        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong class="prodprice">77</strong></td>
        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong class="prodtotal"></strong></td>
        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
  <span class="fa fa-remove"></span> Remove
  </button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td>
          <h5>Subtotal</h5>
        </td>
        <td class="text-right">
          <!--just add this class-->
          <h5><strong class="subtotal">$999.99</strong></h5>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td>
          <h5>Estimated shipping</h5>
        </td>
        <td class="text-right">
          <h5><strong>$9.999.99</strong></h5>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td>
          <h3>Total</h3>
        </td>
        <td class="text-right" id="total">
          <h3><strong>$9.999.99</strong></h3>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></span> Continue Shopping
    </button></td>
        <td>

          <a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/checkout') ?>"><button type="button" 
    class="btn btn-success" >
     Checkout <span class="fa fa-play"></span></a>
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```